# What code do I need to enter to make expo project function?

Tags: github, expo

I am not a developer, but I had an app built a couple months ago. The developer we had won't help us at all anymore (not sure why).

Please excuse me if I don't use proper terms.

So the project was done on Expo. I no longer have access to the original expo project, but I have all the code he wrote in a Github repository.

Is is possible to take the code from Github and paste it into Expo XDE and possibly reproduce the app on Expo? (Or Does that sound possible?)

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this. It is important, that you copy all project files from the GitHub repository into your new Expo project. Don't forget to download all necessary libraries into your new Expo project, e.g. via `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete react native noob, I've been doing this, and  I love it:

1. Develop prototype on https://snack.expo.io

Here I can develop and test on the browser, test on my phones, and on emulators. It's great.

2. When I'm ready to build, I download the code package from the Snack IDE

This downloads a zip file with everything except Expo and imported libraries.

3. I unzip and go into the folder with my terminal and install the libraries.

Inside the folder, I run these commands to install Expo and the regular libraries:

```
$ npm install expo  # install expo
$ npm install  # install a bunch of required libraries
# Then I run these two lines until my project builds
$ npm run web  # try to run  - it will tell me which libraries to install, one by one
$ npm install <library>  # install each library
```

Eventually I'll move to using command-line only, but this is both a no-brainer for a noob like me and it's like training  wheels for me to learn npm and expo.